# python boto3 enter tag name then convert that to ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

how do i use boto3 to get the ARN of a storage gateway by inputting the name?
like this

```
SG_NAME = input("Enter Storage Gateway name: ")

print(SG_ARN)
```

any idea how to convert the Name to ARN?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/storagegateway.html), I believe you will have to call `list_gateways()` and iterate over the response in your Python code until you find a gateway with the name that matches what the user entered.